# Create big query resource using existing big query resource via terraform

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

I written a terraform script to create dataset and table in big query using terraform. I want to create tables with schema already present in a big query resource.

I have used the following lines of code to achieve it -

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "example_dataset" {
  dataset_id = var.dataset_id
  project    = var.project_id
}

data "google_bigquery_table" "existing_tables" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.example_dataset.dataset_id
  project    = var.project_id
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "dynamic_tables" {
  for_each = data.google_bigquery_table.existing_tables.table_ids

  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.example_dataset.dataset_id
  project    = var.project_id
  table_id   = each.key

  schema {
    dynamic "fields" {
      for_each = each.value.schema.fields

      content {
        name = fields.value.name
        type = fields.value.type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the error I am getting is this -

The provider hashicorp/google-beta does not support data source "google_bigquery_dataset".

I think data block is throwing the error and not able to execute the terraform. What can be the alternate or modification to the above code?

Comment: data source "google_bigquery_dataset" is not present in the config in the question. Is that config and/or the error message accurate?

Comment: It is accurate as when I try to create big query dataset and table, I am able to. The data block is causing the issue.